# How to generate a DATETIME based on 6 integers: yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss?

Tags: datetime, dolphindb

For example, yyyy=2022, MM=8, dd=25, HH=14, mm=50, ss=30, how can I get 2022.08.25T14:50:30?

Answer (score 1):

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

gave me this: "2022-08-30T02:32:49.627Z"

then you can remove the last 2 characters off the end. You would also need to fiddle around with time zones to figure out what the difference between your time and the ISO format which I think is based off of toUTCString(), and you would need to account for day light savings.

Answer (score 0):

Use concat to concatenate these integers into strings and parse with [temporalParse](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/t/temporalParse.html) (datetimeParse)

```
yyyy=2022
MM=8
dd=25
HH=14
mm=50
ss=30

s = concat([yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss], "-")
d = datetimeParse(s, "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")
```

There are two ways to solve this problem.  As mentioned above, one is to use concat to concatenate integers into strings and then convert it to a DATETIME (func 1).

You can also convert these integers using func2.

```
yyyy=2022
MM=8
dd=25
HH=14
mm=50
ss=30

def func1(yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss){
    return temporalParse(concat([yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss], "-"), "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")
}
def func2(yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss){
    return datetime(date(month(yyyy*12)+MM-1)+dd-1)+HH*3600+mm*60+ss
}

timer func1(yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss)
timer func2(yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss)
```

Output:

Time elapsed: 0.078 ms

Time elapsed: 0.072 ms

There is not much difference in performance.

If there is a large amount of data, i.e., yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, and ss are vectors, you can use func3.

```
n = 10000000
yyyy=take(2022,n)
MM=rand(1..12,n)
dd=rand(1..28,n)
HH=rand(24,n)
mm=rand(60,n)
ss=rand(60,n)
def func3(yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss){
    return temporalParse((string(yyyy)+"-"+string(MM)+"-"+string(dd)+"-"+string(HH)+"-"+string(mm)+"-"+string(ss)),"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")
}
```

---

```
timer func2(yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss)
timer func3(yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss)
```

Time elapsed: 203.697 ms

Time elapsed: 9571.486 ms